# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config' Python Tkinker

Tags: python

Hey my Code works but it gives an Error.
i Have an Shop where u can buy Code
its long and i think u could do ist in less lines but its my first code. Nothing is copied all my Ideas.

It would be nice if u could check it and maybe find the mistake!

The error is:
"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1921, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Anwender\PycharmProjects\MyGame\Try2Programm.py", line 21, in buying
phy_amount.config(text=phy_global)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'"

I dont want that error but i dont know how to fix it!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox


def imagine():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Lul", "Imagine I could code that shit..")


def close_game():
    root.destroy()


def buying():
    code_to_buy = selected_code.get()
    if code_to_buy == "1":
        global phy_global
        phy_global += 1

        phy_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=phy_global).grid(row=1, column=2)

        phy_amount.config(text=phy_global)

    elif code_to_buy == "2":
        global c_plus_global
        c_plus_global += 1

        c_plus_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=c_plus_global).grid(row=2, column=2)

        c_plus_amount.cofig(text=c_plus_global)
    elif code_to_buy == "3":
        global java_global
        java_global += 1

        java_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=java_global).grid(row=3, column=2)

        java_amount.cofig(text=java_global)
    elif code_to_buy == "4":
        global scratch_global
        scratch_global += 1

        scratch_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=scratch_global).grid(row=4, column=2)

        scratch_amount.cofig(text=scratch_global)

root = Tk()
root.title("Code Shop")
root_img = PhotoImage(file="c:/GUIs_Images/root_img.png")
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, root_img)

# **** Top Frame ****

head_frame = LabelFrame(root, padx=92, pady=10)
head_frame.pack(padx=40, pady=10)

head_title = Label(head_frame, text="Code Shop")
head_title.grid(row=0, column=0)

# **** Middle Frame ****

middle_frame = LabelFrame(root, padx=10, pady=6)  # 110, 60
middle_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

# **** Headline ****

code_name = Label(middle_frame, text="Codes for Sale:")
code_price = Label(middle_frame, text="Sold for:")
code_amount = Label(middle_frame, text="Amount of Code:")

code_name.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
code_price.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
code_amount.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)

# **** Type of Codes ****

CODES = [
    ("Phy Code", "1"),
    ("C++ Code", "2"),
    ("Java Code", "3"),
    ("Scratch Code", "4"),
]

selected_code = StringVar()
selected_code.set(0)

row = 0

for text, code in CODES:
    row += 1
    Radiobutton(middle_frame, text=text, variable=selected_code, value=code).grid(row=row, column=0, sticky=W)

# **** Price of Code ****

phy_price = Label(middle_frame, text="12 $")
c_plus_price = Label(middle_frame, text="12 $")
java_price = Label(middle_frame, text="12 $")
scratch_price = Label(middle_frame, text="12 $")

phy_price.grid(row=1, column=1)
c_plus_price.grid(row=2, column=1)
java_price.grid(row=3, column=1)
scratch_price.grid(row=4, column=1)

# **** Amount of Code ****
phy_global = 0
c_plus_global = 0
java_global = 0
scratch_global = 0

zero_code_1 = Label(middle_frame, text="/").grid(row=1, column=2)
zero_code_2 = Label(middle_frame, text="/").grid(row=2, column=2)
zero_code_3 = Label(middle_frame, text="/").grid(row=3, column=2)
zero_code_4 = Label(middle_frame, text="/").grid(row=4, column=2)

my_button = Button(middle_frame, text="Buy", padx=20, command=buying).grid(row=10, column=1)

# **** Bottom Frame ****

bottom_frame = LabelFrame(root, padx=10, pady=10, )
bottom_frame.pack(padx=40, pady=20, side=BOTTOM)

button_games = Button(bottom_frame, text="Games", command=close_game, padx=16)
button_games.pack(padx=3, side=LEFT)

button_settings = Button(bottom_frame, text="Settings", command=imagine, padx=13)
button_settings.pack(padx=3, side=LEFT)

button_help = Button(bottom_frame, text="Help", command=imagine, padx=20)
button_help.pack(padx=3, side=LEFT)

button_quit = Button(bottom_frame, text="Exit", command=close_game, padx=20)
button_quit.pack(padx=3, side=RIGHT)


root.mainloop()
```

Its my first big code :)

Comment: The error occurred because `Label(middle_frame, text=phy_global).grid(row=1, column=2)` return `None`.

Comment: 99 % occurences of "NoneType object has no attribute..." come from a function unexpectedly returning None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here, and it is a very common problem with tkinter code, is these lines:

```
        phy_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=phy_global).grid(row=1, column=2)
        phy_amount.config(text=phy_global)
...
        c_plus_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=c_plus_global).grid(row=2, column=2)
        c_plus_amount.cofig(text=c_plus_global)
...
        java_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=java_global).grid(row=3, column=2)
        java_amount.cofig(text=java_global)
...
        scratch_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=scratch_global).grid(row=4, column=2)
        scratch_amount.cofig(text=scratch_global)
```

It is natural to try to do "pipelines" like this, where you do `object(xxx).option().option()`, but Tkinter doesn't support that.  The `grid` function returns None, so you have lost your object instance.  If you need to save your Label instance, you have to write it like this:

```
        phy_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=phy_global)
        phy_amount.grid(row=1, column=2)
        phy_amount.config(text=phy_global)
...
        c_plus_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=c_plus_global)
        c_plus_amount.grid(row=2, column=2)
        c_plus_amount.config(text=c_plus_global)
...
        java_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=java_global)
        java_amount.grid(row=3, column=2)
        java_amount.config(text=java_global)
...
        scratch_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=scratch_global)
        scratch_amount.grid(row=4, column=2)
        scratch_amount.config(text=scratch_global)
```

Since you're already setting the text in the constructor, you don't actually need the `config` lines here, but the principle is still valid.  BTW, you misspelled `config` several times.  I've fixed that here.

Comment: thank u sooo much i changed it and it worked!! Its my first question and post here und you were so nice thanks :D

Answer (score -1):

I fixed all of the mistakes, and some disclaimers:

1. if you need to use global varibles prefer to use a class instead,
   and pass the 'global' elements as atributes of object
2. onclick funcions is basicly lambdas, if you need pass arguments for them, create a wraper like

```py
wraper_random = lambda: your_function('arg 1','arg2')
onclick= wraper_random
```

3. your gui is very beatifull and organized

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

class Store:
    
    @staticmethod
    def imagine():
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Lul", "Imagine I could code that shit..")

    @staticmethod
    def close_game(root:Tk):
        root.destroy()


    def buying(self,selected_code:StringVar,middle_frame:LabelFrame):
        code_to_buy = selected_code.get()

        if code_to_buy == "1":
            self.phy += 1
            phy_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=self.phy).grid(row=1, column=2)
            

        elif code_to_buy == "2":
            self.c_plus_plus += 1
            c_plus_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=self.c_plus_plus).grid(row=2, column=2)

        elif code_to_buy == "3":
            self.java += 1
            java_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=self.java).grid(row=3, column=2)

        elif code_to_buy == "4":
            self.scratchl += 1
            scratch_amount = Label(middle_frame, text=self.scratchl).grid(row=4, column=2)



    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.title("Code Shop")
        try:
          root_img = PhotoImage(file="c:/GUIs_Images/root_img.png")
          root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, root_img)
        except:pass 

        # **** Top Frame ****
        head_frame = LabelFrame(root, padx=92, pady=10)
        head_frame.pack(padx=40, pady=10)

        head_title = Label(head_frame, text="Code Shop")
        head_title.grid(row=0, column=0)


        # **** Middle Frame ****

        middle_frame = LabelFrame(root, padx=10, pady=6)  # 110, 60
        middle_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)


        # **** Headline ****

        code_name = Label(middle_frame, text="Codes for Sale:")
        code_price = Label(middle_frame, text="Sold for:")
        code_amount = Label(middle_frame, text="Amount of Code:")

        code_name.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        code_price.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        code_amount.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)


        # **** Type of Codes ****

        CODES = {
            "Phy Code":"1",
            "C++ Code":"2",
            "Java Code":"3",
            "Scratch Code":"4"
        }
        selected_code = StringVar()
        selected_code.set(0)

        row = 0

        for text in CODES.keys():
            code = CODES[text]
            row += 1
            Radiobutton(middle_frame, text=text, variable=selected_code, value=code).grid(row=row, column=0, sticky=W)


        # **** Price of Code ****
        phy_price = Label(middle_frame, text="12 $")
        c_plus_price = Label(middle_frame, text="12 $")
        java_price = Label(middle_frame, text="12 $")
        scratch_price = Label(middle_frame, text="12 $")

        phy_price.grid(row=1, column=1)
        c_plus_price.grid(row=2, column=1)
        java_price.grid(row=3, column=1)
        scratch_price.grid(row=4, column=1)

        # **** Amount of Code ****
        self.phy = 0
        self.c_plus_plus = 0
        self.java = 0
        self.scratchl = 0

        zero_code_1 = Label(middle_frame, text="/").grid(row=1, column=2)
        zero_code_2 = Label(middle_frame, text="/").grid(row=2, column=2)
        zero_code_3 = Label(middle_frame, text="/").grid(row=3, column=2)
        zero_code_4 = Label(middle_frame, text="/").grid(row=4, column=2)

        wraper_buying = lambda:self.buying(selected_code,middle_frame)
        my_button = Button(middle_frame, text="Buy", padx=20, command=wraper_buying).grid(row=10, column=1)

        # **** Bottom Frame ****

        bottom_frame = LabelFrame(root, padx=10, pady=10, )
        bottom_frame.pack(padx=40, pady=20, side=BOTTOM)
        

        button_games = Button(bottom_frame, text="Games", command=self.imagine, padx=16)
        button_games.pack(padx=3, side=LEFT)

        button_settings = Button(bottom_frame, text="Settings", command=self.imagine, padx=13)
        button_settings.pack(padx=3, side=LEFT)

        button_help = Button(bottom_frame, text="Help", command=self.imagine, padx=20)
        button_help.pack(padx=3, side=LEFT)

        wraper_close = lambda:self.close_game(root)
        button_quit = Button(bottom_frame, text="Exit", command=wraper_close, padx=20)
        button_quit.pack(padx=3, side=RIGHT)

        root.mainloop()



Store()
```

Comment: kkkkk, it fix the gui problem, and implement in a better way, thats all

Comment: Your "phy_amount", "c_plus_amount", "java_amount" and "scratch_amount" variables will all be `None`.  THAT was the original problem.  As it turns out, with your changes, you don't need to save them, which means you might as well remove them.  They serve no purpose.

Comment: of course, it could be implemented in a better way, but its not usefull, now I ask, did you try to run the code?, or even tryed to understand how it works? , I fixed it, in my way, thats the difference bro, there is people that talks, and people thats makes thing happen, deal with it kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: I understand.  You posted something that works.  However, you did not answer his question here, which was "why do I get this error?".  Thus, he is quite likely to make the same mistake again.  That's why this is a less effective answer.

Comment: Thank u, i know i could change a lot of things but i dont know want they do and i want so understand them. I will stay with my version at first but thank you. I realy like my gui too. :3